# Angular $scope set to another $scope value not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, nested, angularjs-controller

I am trying to give one $scope variable the value of another $scope variable. Can someone tell me what is going wrong? Take a look at the simple plunker for details:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TlKnd2fM5ajrlkKKhKZ1?p=preview

I know I am missing a fundamental concept in the way $scope works, but I can't pinpoint what it is. Somebody slap me and give me that 'Ahaaaa' moment if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you assign to the `greeting` property does not get reevaluated when `username` changes. `greeting` gets stuck with the initial (blank) value of `username`. You could set up a watch on `username` and modify greeting when `username` changes, or you could change the view:

```
<div ng-controller="Parent">
    {{username}} {{greeting}}
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And don't use `username` when assigning to `greeting`:

```
$scope.greeting = 'is so confused.';
```

Here's an [updated example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Y8pfXGf2Vfux35SFsak?p=preview).

Comment: Ah! I did need the username variable inside the greeting variable so watch is the way to go! I made a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TlKnd2fM5ajrlkKKhKZ1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, but you can't expect `greeting` to get updated every time `username` changes since the binding (that creates a `$watch`) is done in `greeting`, which is a string. So everytime a `$digest` loop occurs it will just re evaluate your variable `greeting` to the same result ("is so confused.").

You need to bind the property you want to maintain updated like this:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l3UxoeGoXE9amuElpgYr?p=preview)